# Why is videojs disabled when i close popup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I'm trying to implement video in popup, but when I close popup and re-open it, video doesn't work at all. Why is that?

This is my code:

```
<video className="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "youtube": { "ytControls": 2 }, "autoplay": true }' width="480" height="320">
    <source type="video/youtube" src={this.props.YouTubeURL}/>
</video>
```

Show popup function:

```
showYoutubePopup(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        showPopupYoutube: true
    });
}
```

Close popup function:

```
hideYoutubePopup(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        showPopupYoutube: false
    });
}
```

Comment: I think there is more info we need to help you. Can you debug so you can provide more insights to this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-modal-dialog.html
```

If you dont want to use videojs's baked in modal, you can try to "pause" video before you close custom popup.